# How do I send a parameter containing a slash in GET request, via jQuery's .ajax() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I need to create the following URL to call an API via jQuery's .ajax() function:

`https://www.airnowapi.org/aq/forecast/zipCode/?format=application/json&zipCode=02144&date=2016-11-26&distance=25&API_KEY=API_KEY`

I know how to form this by just putting together the string on its own, but that seems like an unnecessary workaround and wouldn't allow me to use `.ajax()`. I'd have to do a lot of work manually that this function should do for me.

The trouble is this part: `format=application/json`, because when I give that as a parameter in the settings object I pass to `.ajax()`, it escapes the slash to `%2F`, and the API doesn't accept the request. I've also tried just leaving out the format parameter, but I get a 500 server error. The request works perfectly if I just type it into my web browser, but not if this parameter is missing or doesn't include the slash (can't be escaped). I need to either prevent `.ajax()` from encoding the slash this way, or decode it again somehow BEFORE it reaches the API server.

I've already searched Google and StackOverflow for answers, but without any luck. I understand how to encode and decode escape characters, but I can't intercept it inside a jQuery function I didn't write. Unless I tried to rewrite that function, based on the jQuery source code, but again that seems like a big workaround for a simple issue. For reference, here is the relevant part of my code:

```
function getData(query, callback) {
    var settings = {
        url: state.apis.airNow.BASE_URL,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: callback,
        data: {
            format: "application/json",
            zipCode: query,
            distance: 25,
            API_KEY: state.apis.airNow.API_KEY
        }
    };
    $.ajax(settings);
}
```

How do I get `.ajax()` to submit `format=application/json` in the exact form the API expects, or is there another similar function I should be using instead?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem is that `$.ajax()` will convert your `data` object to a query string to be appended to the url. Which works great...except for the fact that url encoding doesn't fly with that API. Could you modify the `url` parameter of the settings object to include the format portion of the query? Something like `url: state.apis.airNow.BASE_URL + '?format=application/json',` ?

Comment: @SimianAngel, I thought of that, but if `$.ajax()` has to encode the rest of the settings, it's going to add another '?' after the first parameter. I should be able to solve it, though, through @Brian 's answer below. Will respond to that one and probably upvote as soon as I try it out and make sure it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `processData:false` and manually construct the query string. Worth noting that my `makeQS` function will not handle nested objects or arrays in its current state. The only options besides this is to pass the params on the url or to intercept the AJAX request and alter the URL

**processData solution:**

```
function makeQS(obj){
    var params = [];
    for(var key in obj){
        params.push(key + '=' + obj[key]);
    }
    return params.join('&');
}


function getData(query, callback) {
    var settings = {
        url: state.apis.airNow.BASE_URL,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: callback,
        processData: false,
        data: makeQS({
            format: "application/json",
            zipCode: query,
            distance: 25,
            API_KEY: state.apis.airNow.API_KEY
        })
    };
    $.ajax(settings);
}
```

If you want to pass them on the URL instead you could just change settings.url to something like:

```
settings.url = state.apis.airNow.BASE_URL + '?' + makeQS({
            format: "application/json",
            zipCode: query,
            distance: 25,
            API_KEY: state.apis.airNow.API_KEY
        })
```

It's probably also worth noting that as no encoding at all is done on the parameters that characters like & and = within any of the parameters will very likely cause unexpected behavior from the API endpoint which is one of the reasons why an endpoint like this generally should take URI encoded GET parameters
`

Comment: Thanks, @Brian. My site is now submitting the proper query string and URL.

The API is STILL not accepting the request — interestingly, when I cut and paste the submitted URL into my browser, it does return the expected JSON object, just not when it comes through my Javascript — but this seems to be an entirely separate problem from the one I asked about here, so I'll hack away at it for a bit before bothering anyone here again.

Comment: I'd suggest using Chromes network tab and comparing the two requests to see what is different then if you can't troubleshoot it in browser maybe try generating the request using another tool/language you're familiar with (curl, wget or maybe a node or php script might do the trick). The only other thought is does the API spec outline any other headers or fields that must or must not be included or does the error provide any further information that might aid in troubleshooting?

Comment: FYI, I solved this second problem since the previous post. It had nothing to do with the first one, but apparently the API doesn't support CORS (not specified anywhere in the docs) so we had to send the request from a backend proxy. It's all working now. Thanks for your help, Brian!

Comment: You're very welcome! Proxying it might be useful for feature addition/caching/consolidation etc. also it would prevent abuse of your API key which may be why they don't support CORS my bad for missing that point - might have saved you a lot of time! Glad you've solved it - hopefully my answer will be helpful for anyone who comes across a finicky API endpoint :).

Comment: Yeah, proxying is a good idea in any case. I'm still a web-dev student, though, and we haven't covered back-end topics yet at all. My mentor had to mostly do that part for me, which wouldn't have been necessary if they supported CORS, but I'll learn to do it for myself soon.